# Why can't I sort columns in my PyQt5 QTableWidget using UserRole data?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to sort my QTableWidget columns by the values stored in the user role of each QTableWidgetItem, but I am unable to do so. I have enabled sorting with `self.setSortingEnabled(True)`, and I have set the data in each QTableWidgetItem with `item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, f'M - {r}')` and `item.setData(Qt.UserRole, r)`. However, when I try to sort the columns by the values stored in the user role, it sorts the columns by the values stored in the display role instead.

Here is a minimal working example of my code:

```py
from random import randint

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QWidget, QGridLayout, \
    QTableWidgetItem, QPushButton


class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def populate(self):
        self.clear()
        self.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setRowCount(200)
        for row in range(500):
            for column in range(3):
                r = randint(0, 1000)
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, f'M - {r}')
                item.setData(Qt.UserRole, r)
                self.setItem(row, column, item)


class MainApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = Table()
        self.button = QPushButton('Roll')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.table.populate)

        layout = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(layout)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        layout.setLayout(grid)

        grid.addWidget(self.button)
        grid.addWidget(self.table)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    main_app = MainApp()
    main_app.showMaximized()
    app.exec()
```

[image: Example]

Additionally, I tried using EditRole, but the values that appear in the table are not the values from DisplayRole. For example, in the code below, I set item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, f'M - {r}'), but even though r is an integer, the display role value is a string ('M - {r}'). I was hoping that sorting by UserRole or EditRole would sort based on the integer value of r, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```py
item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, f'M - {r}')
item.setData(Qt.EditRole, int(r))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting is always based on `Qt.DisplayRole`.

Trying to use the `EditRole` is pointless, as the [`setData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData) documentation points out:

> **Note:** The default implementation treats `Qt::EditRole` and `Qt::DisplayRole` as referring to the same data.

The `Qt.UserRole` is a custom role that could be used for anything (and containing *any* type) and by default is not used for anything in Qt. Setting a value with the `UserRole` doesn't change the sorting, because Qt knows nothing about its existence or how the value should be used.

Since you are using *strings* for the sorting, the result is that numbers are not sorted as you may think: for instance "120" is smaller than "13", because "12" comes before "13".

The only occurrence in which the `DisplayRole` properly sorts number values is when it is *explicitly* set with a number:

```py
item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, r)
```

Which will not work for you, as you want to show the "M - " prefix. Also, a common mistake is trying to use that in the constructor:

```py
item = QTableWidgetItem(r)
```

And while the syntax is correct, its usage is wrong, as the [integer constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#QTableWidgetItem) of QTableWidgetItem is used for other purposes.

If you want to support custom sorting, you must create a QTableWidgetItem subclass and implement the [`<`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#operator-lt) operator, which, in Python, is the [`__lt__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__lt__) magic method:

```py
class SortUserRoleItem(QTableWidgetItem):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.data(Qt.UserRole) < other.data(Qt.UserRole)
```

Then you have to create new items using that class. Note that:

- you should always try to use existing items, instead of continuously creating new ones;
- as explained in the [`setItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setItem) documentation, you should always *disable* sorting before adding new items, especially when using a loop, otherwise the table will be constantly sorted at each insertion (thus making further insertion inconsistent);
- you're using the a range (500) inconsistent with the row count (200);
- you should also set an [item prototype](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setItemPrototype) based on the subclass above;

```py
class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.setItemPrototype(SortUserRoleItem())

    def populate(self):
        self.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setRowCount(200)
        for row in range(200):
            for column in range(3):
                r = randint(0, 1000)
                item = self.item(row, column)
                if not item:
                    item = SortUserRoleItem()
                    self.setItem(row, column, item)
                item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, 'M - {}'.format(r))
                item.setData(Qt.UserRole, r)
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
```

Note that, as an alternative, you could use a custom delegate, then just set the value of the item as an integer (as shown above) and override the [`displayText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#displayText):

```py
class PrefixDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def displayText(self, text, locale):
        if isinstance(text, int):
            text = f'M - {text}'
        return text


class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setItemDelegate(PrefixDelegate(self))
        # ...

    def populate(self):
        # ...
                item = self.item(row, column)
                if not item:
                    item = QTableWidgetItem()
                    self.setItem(row, column, item)
                item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a QTableView instead. Widgets are meant for very basic use cases. It's important to invoke `setSortRole` on the model. Also, your `setData` arguments were in reverse order, correct is `data, role`.

```
from random import randint
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table_view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table_view.setSortingEnabled(True)
        
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setSortRole(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        self.table_view.setModel(self.model)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Roll')

        layout = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(layout)
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        layout.setLayout(grid)

        grid.addWidget(self.button)
        grid.addWidget(self.table_view)

        self.button.clicked.connect(
            self.populate
        )

    def populate(self):
        self.table_view.model().clear()
        for _ in range(500):
            r = randint(0, 1000)
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            item.setData(f'M - {r}', QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            item.setData(r, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            self.table_view.model().appendRow(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    main_app = MainApp()
    main_app.showMaximized()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Sorry to be blunt but your code has many issues: 1. PyQt decorators only make sense for functions of a QObject subclass (decorating a class is pointless, and `Populate` is a class, not a function), also, the `pyqtSlot` decorator is rarely needed; 2. using a class for that is completely pointless, just use a function; 3. that "class" actually creates 1500 rows, since you called `appendRow()` within the nested `for`; 4. if you want to use explicit imports, just use the required ones, otherwise use wildcard imports (QTableWidget/QTableWidgetItem are never used, as you specifically pointed out).

Comment: All good suggestions and I've edited the answer.
Regarding class usage, I was trying to follow the structure Collaxd was using as closely as possible and yes, it's a bad practice.

Comment: But the OP never used a class for that, their class was required for subclassing the tablewidget, if you don't need that, creating a class for `Populate` is completely pointless and useless.